# Ruby - how to remove some chars from string?

Tags: ruby, string, whitespace

I have following strings:

```
"  asfagds gfdhd"sss dg    "
"sdg "dsg          "
```

desired output:

```
asfagds gfdhd"sss dg
sdg "dsg
```

(Empty spaces removed from the front and end of the strings, as well as leading and trailing double quotes.)

I have a big file with these lines and I need them format to our needs... How could I remove the `"` from the start and end of the respective file and remove the white spaces from the start and end of the file?

Comment: Wait, your lines are all `"`<sometext>`"`? And do you want to remove whitespaces from the start and end of the **file** or the **line**?

Comment: The question is highly sloppy and/or inconsistent. 1. You seem to be double quoting the initial strings, but not escaping the double quotation within the string. How are we supposed to know which quotations are the really meant? 2. In the desired outputs, you do not have quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`string.strip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-strip) or [`string.strip!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-strip).

```
"  asfagds gfdhd\"sss dg    ".strip
"asfagds gfdhd\"sss dg"
```

Be aware that `strip` removes all whitespaces (fe. tabs, newlines), not just spaces.
If you want to remove just spaces use:

```
string.gsub /^ *| *$/, ''
```

If you want to remove `"` as well:

```
string.gsub /^" *| *"$/, ''
```

Answer (score 2):

If the data in the file is clean and uniform, then this should do

'"  asfagds gfdhd"sss dg    "'[1..-2].strip

If the data is not clean, you may need to do a strip before too.. (ie if there are trailing spaces after the closing quotation marks.

'"  asfagds gfdhd"sss dg    "'.strip[1..-2].strip

Really depends on how clean the data in the file is.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strip`:

```
 "     Hello World     ".strip #=> "Hello World"
```

Or to only strip from the left/right use `lstrip` and `rstrip` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
irb> '"  asfagds gfdhd"sss dg    "'[1..-2].strip
 => "asfagds gfdhd"sss dg"
```

take the [1,n-1] substring, remove whitespace